# How does push state enable "HTML 5 style" URLs

Tags: javascript, pushstate

I'm reading [this doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#base-href) which says:

> The router uses the browser's history.pushState for navigation. **Thanks
>   to pushState, you can make in-app URL** paths look the way you want them
>   to look, e.g. localhost:3000/crisis-center. The in-app URLs can be
>   indistinguishable from server URLs.

Can anyone please explain with an example how exactly it makes it possible and **why it wasn't possible** until `pushState` was implemented?

Comment: [see mdn's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method)

Comment: i'll try to answer this more in-depth later as far as I know, it comes down to navigation. In a single-page-app, if you press the back button without pushState, the browser will just go back to the previous page it was on